# How do I continue from BusyBox (initramfs) prompt?

Tags: boot, command-line

Can somebody help? I turned my computer on and I don't know how to login or make it work.

This is the text that showed on the screen:

```
BusyBox v1.30.01 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu 6.4) built-in shell (ash) 
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.
```

When I plugged in the external keyboard this writing showed up...

```
(intramfs) yyt [ 41.04787274 usb4-port2: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
```

[image: initramfs]
With or without usb devices connected it shows the first command...

If anyone can help I would obviously greatly appreciate it... Sorry if my question isn't as clear as it needs to be... I am still new to this tech!

Comment: Please change your question title to something informative that explains your problem; you're much more likely to attract the attention of knowledgeable individuals that way. "How do I continue?" is meaninglessly vague.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post (1) Ubuntu release/version; (2) hardware specifications; (3) describe how/when this happened; has it ever worked? How was Ubuntu installed? etc.

Comment: Unplug all of your USB devices and see if the computer boots normally then. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thanks. heynemma, it doesnt make a difference... Still comes up with the first text/command... Hope u get this comment, dont know how to comment on ur profile...

Comment: See if it'll boot to a Ubuntu Live USB. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: How do u boot to a ubuntu live usb? Or how get ubuntu live on a usb?

Answer (score -1):

When I hit into this, I used `exit` to close out of intramfs. Then followed the suggestions to fix file corruptions using the file system check (fsck).
E.g. something like `fsck -yf /dev/mapper/xxxx`

Comment: The question has nothing to do with error correction.